# How to fix the classpath/ environment issue and method error when executing on Unix?

Tags: java, bash, unix, classpath

My version of Linux/Unix:
Linux localhost.localdomain 2.6.32-358.18.1.e16.i686 #1 SMP Wed Aug 28 14:27:42 UTC 2013 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux

2.6.32-358.18.1.e16.i686

I'm trying to run on Unix using terminal with javac TouchyWindow.java and then java TouchyWindow. I have 2 problems about this program.

Problem #1: When I compile it, I need to export "export CLASSPATH=.:$HOME/objectdraw.jar" for this  program every time when I try to run it.

I want unix automatically run objectdraw when I try to compile javac TouchyWindow.java. The teacher said it was possible to do it and he gave me a hint:

(Aside: Unix/Linux allows you define environment variables for configuration. The java
CLASSPATH variable is a useful variable. If you edit $HOME/.bashrc and place the following
definition export CLASSPATH=.:$HOME/objectdraw.jar then any java program you compile/run that uses the objectdraw library will not require and explicit classpath definition when running java or javac. If you have downloaded the Virtual Machine (VM), you can see an example of this in the ~cs11xyz/.bashrc file. The definition only becomes active when you login or create a new terminal.)

Problem #2: If I execute "export CLASSPATH=.:$HOME/objectdraw.jar" when I compile TouchyWindow.java, it did compile successfully, but, when I command java TouchyWindow to see the reult, it did not work and the error is this: "Error: Main method not found in class TouchyWindow, please define the main method as: public static void main(String[] args)"

Someone told me to just change the method to public static void main(String[] args). It could work. But, my teacher's website has the same program example just like the code I showed below without using method "public static void main(String[] args)" and still works perfectly fine. If you want to see the example, here is the link: http://eventfuljava.cs.williams.edu/sampleProgs/ch1/textbook/TouchyWindow/TouchyWindow.html
If you click on the source code, you can see that the program is not using public static void main(String[] args).

Please Help.

How to fix these problems, please?

```
here is my .bashrc

# pre-existing bashrc file may have been moved to a file named
# "${HOME}/.bashrc.old". Check the commands in that file be
# sure they are still needed.

if [ -r ${HOME}/.bashrc.old ]
then
echo "----------------------------------------------"
echo "About to run commands in your old bashrc file."
echo "Delete the file .bashrc.old, or edit .bashrc if these commands"
echo "should not be run anymore."
echo "----------------------------------------------"
source ${HOME}/.bashrc.old
echo "----------------------------------------------"
echo "Done running commands in your old bashrc file."
echo "----------------------------------------------"
fi



here is my .bash_profile



#AUTION: if you choose to make adjustments to PATH,
# it is usually advisable to *add* to the existing PATH
# rather than resetting PATH completely.  By adding, there
# is less chance of inadvertently losing important elements.
# For example:  set path = ( $path ${HOME}/bin )
[ -r .acms.debug ] && echo EXITING .bashrc >&2

[ -r .acms.debug ] && echo ENTERED .bash_profile >&2
public=${public:-/public}

# All the usual setup is done by the following line.  Any additions
# you make should come after it.
#
[ -r $public/bash_profile.adjunct ] && . $public/bash_profile.adjunct

# When this file was first placed in your home directory, a
# pre-existing bashrc file may have been moved to a file named
# "${HOME}/.bashrc.old". Check the commands in that file be
# sure they are still needed.


# You may add commands to the end of this file as needed.
#
# CAUTION: if you choose to make adjustments to PATH,
# it is usually advisable to *add* to the existing PATH
# rather than resetting PATH completely.  By adding, there
# is less chance of inadvertently losing important elements.
# For example:  set path = ( $path ${HOME}/bin )
[ -r .acms.debug ] && echo EXITED .bash_profile >&2




import objectdraw.*;
import java.awt.*;
public class TouchyWindow extends WindowController{
public void OnMousePress( Location Point){
new Text("I'm Touched!", 40, 40, canvas);
}
public void OnMouseRelease( Location Point){
canvas.clear();
}
}
```

Comment: Can you edit your post so that code is in code blocks and the question is not? There are nice editor buttons to help you do this.

Comment: what is the result of the command `javac TouchyWindow.java`?  if there's an error, please give the error.  see also the Oracle explanation of classpath.  What is the result of `% echo $CLASSPATH`?  See  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html    GIYF.

Comment: It says : TouchyWindow.java:1: error: package objectdraw does not exist
import objectdraw.*;
^
TouchyWindow.java:3: error: cannot find symbol
    public class TouchyWindow extends WindowController{
                                      ^
  symbol: class WindowController
TouchyWindow.java:4: error: cannot find symbol
        public void OnMousePress( Location Point){
                                  ^
  symbol:   class Location
  location: class TouchyWindow
TouchyWindow.java:7: error: cannot find symbol
        public void OnMouseRelease( Location Point)
                                    ^

Comment: public void OnMouseRelease( Location Point){
                                    ^
  symbol:   class Location
  location: class TouchyWindow
TouchyWindow.java:5: error: cannot find symbol
            new Text("I'm Touched!", 40, 40, canvas);
                ^
  symbol:   class Text
  location: class TouchyWindow
TouchyWindow.java:5: error: cannot find symbol
            new Text("I'm Touched!", 40, 40, canvas);
                                             ^
  symbol:   variable canvas
  location: class TouchyWindow
TouchyWindow.java:8: error: cannot find symbol
            canvas.clear()

Comment: ^
  symbol:   variable canvas
  location: class TouchyWindow
7 errors

Comment: djeikyb: where to find the button? I'm so new to here...

Comment: @Thufir When I command java TouchyWindow to see the reult, it did not work even If I export "export CLASSPATH=.:$HOME/objectdraw.jar"and the error is this: "Error: Main method not found in class TouchyWindow, please define the main method as: public static void main(String[] args)"   Help,please.

Comment: fix the question to include all of that information, please.  be very careful in your usage of the format buttons.  Include your **source code**.   basically, you need a `public static void main(String[] args){}` line (method main) in your code.  remove all that bash stuff, this is not about bash IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

Use any text editor to add the `export` command line you provided to the end of your `.bashrc`. Or, my preference for environment variables that do not need to be adjusted for nested shell processes, add the line to the end of your `.bash_profile` or `.profile` file as appropriate.

Once the change is made, you can make Bash rerun the file to pick up the changes with:

```
. .bashrc
```

or:

```
. .bash_profile
```

or:

```
. .profile
```

...depending on which file you edited. However, reprocessing these files, especially the `.bashrc` file which is processed every time a new `bash` command is started, may adjust settings such as shell prompts which may be set to reflect the level of nested interactive shell sessions which have been invoked. To avoid that, simply execute your `export` command line once in each open terminal window to set up the evironment for your current log in session. The edited file will then take care of the setting the next time you log in.

Note that this might still not work quite right depenting on your GUI setup. It will work if you log in directly to a shell prompt, but that is now rare. If the `env` command does not list the `CLASSPATH` environment variable or list it with the correct value the next time you log in and enter `env` at a shell prompt in a terminal window, then you will have to find out how environment variables can be set for your GUI's window manager. If that is necessary and you come back to StackOverflow for help, you will need to provide detailed information about the version of Unix/Linux you are using as well as the window manager for your GUI.

Comment: Hi Ned. The teacher said we don't have to execute the export command line every time when open terminal window to set up the environment for the current log in session. Here is the lint from him: (Aside: Unix/Linux allows you define environment variables for configuration. The java CLASSPATH variable is a useful variable. If you edit $HOME/.bashrc and place the following definition export CLASSPATH=.:$HOME/objectdraw.jar

Comment: then any java program you compile/run that uses the objectdraw library will not require and explicit classpath definition when running java or javac. If you have downloaded the Virtual Machine you can see an example of this in the ~cs11xyz/.bashrc file. The definition only becomes active when you login or create a new terminal.)

Comment: @thufir I understood what you are saying. However, if go to this website and it will show an example of "TouchyWindow" on appletviewer. And, when you check the source file, you can see that the example is running perfectly fine without using public static void main(String[] args){} (main method). Would you tell me why it that and why I tried to compile the same code on my own and it said "Error: Main method not found in class TouchyWindow, please define the main method as: public static void main(String[] args)"  Please Help!

Comment: @user3175955 Adding the `export` line to `$HOME/.bashrc` will mean you do not have to explicitly invoke the command in future terminal windows you open which are running the `bash` shell. However, editing the file will not add the environment variable to any `bash` shells that are already running. For that, you need to invoke the `export` command line or `. .bashrc` in each running shell, close all of your open terminal windows and their running shells and open new terminal windows, or log out and back in...

Comment: Nowontny I'm Adding the export line to $HOME/, so I do not have to explicitly invoke the command in future terminal windows you open which are running the bash shell. The problem is: how to do it? I tried to add "export CLASSPATH=.:$HOME/objectdraw.jar" at the end of the command line of $HOME/.bashrc. But, the result did not change, I still have to execute "export CLASSPATH=.:$HOME/objectdraw.jar" before I compile TouchyWindow.java

Comment: @user3175955 When you say you added the `export` "at the end of the command line of $HOME/.bashrc" do you mean you opened the `$HOME/.bashrc` file in an editor and added the full `export CLASSPATH=.:$HOME/objectdraw.jar` command as the last line of the file or that you edited `$HOME/.bash_profile` and appended the `export` command to a line in the file something like `. $HOME/.bashrc`? You should be doing the former, logging out and back in or, for testing purposes, starting a subshell by directly invoking `bash`, and then verifying your work with `env | egrep CLASSPATH` or `echo $CLASSPATH`.